# I have database issues when processing batch requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Data doesn't save as expected when I processing batch requests to my ExpressJS app.

I have the following endpoint that execute consecutively to function :

```
app.post("/save", function1, function2)



...


exports.function1 = async (req, res, next) => {
     //...
  await data1.save()
}

exports.function2 = async (req, res, next) => {
         //...
     await data2.save()
    }
```

Basically both function purpose are mainly saving data to my mongoDb database by adding new informations to an already existing document . basically, the typical data type is like this :

```
{
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2",
  "key3" : {
     "subKey1" : "subValu1",
     "subKey2" : "subValue2",
  }
}
```

Data save as expected when I make a single request manually or when I execute a very small batch (like 5 requests batch) .

But if I execute a batch of 30+ requests, everything fail and instead of having the data saved in my document, i have a `null` . Even if I separate the 30 requests execution by 10 seconds between each of them.

After days of investigating , I can't really say what's cause that.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

In your functions invoke `next()` on last line.

Comment: I already invoked next in my real code even if it's not showed in the above example. So I think the problem is somewhere else. Also Like I said all is good as far as I make individual request or small batch requets. Things get worst when I make a big batch of dozen/hundreds requests.

Comment: Are you using connections pooling or creating new connections in your functions

Comment: I am not using connections pooling just making basic operations like `await xxxx.findById()` or `await xxxxx.save()`

Comment: Open connection at start, before declaring any route, close connection in uncaught exception

Comment: This is actually already set as it in my `mongoose.js`. So I don't think the problem comes from it. Basically mongoose listen for an error and if so, the connection close.